# "Джунглевый туризм" – возможно ли такое словосочетание?

Tags: грамотная-речь

(Эта фраза немного режет слух)

Answer (score 1):

Вполне корректная фраза. Джунгли - разновидность леса, а словосочетания "лесной туризм", "таежный туризм" - привычны для нас. Прилагательное "джунглевый" конкретизирует местность, по которой предполагается путешествие, просто оно образовано от заимствованния, находящегося во множественном числе, возможно потому и режет слух. От существительных во множественном числе образуются достаточно логичные прилагательные: сани - санный (спорт, след), ножницы - ножничный (разрез).